# How to show this set is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function and let $c$ be some constant. Show that the following set $$s= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) \le c \}$$ is convex.

Looking for a hint.

Comment: Sorry for the editing confusion. I realise I don't know how latex works here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Well, just write down a convex combination of elements in $s$ and verify that it belong to $s$. You will find the convexity of $f$ useful for this.

Comment: **Note:** I didn't answer the question completely since it could be homework and since the OP asked for a hint. I hope that it is appropriate to post this as an answer.

Comment: So every point in between points of the set can be written as: a1x1 + a2x2 + ...anxn where every ai >= 0 and the sum of the a values is 1. How can it be shown this belongs to s?

Comment: @Greg: What does it mean to belong to s?

Comment: if an element is in s  then f (λx1 + (1 − λ)x2 ) ≤ λf (x1 ) + (1 − λ)f (x2 ) which is ≤ c .... I'm just confused how c fits in with this problem.

Comment: @Greg: there you have the proof: if x1 and x2 are in s then the line segment they define is totally contained in s, and so s is convex, by definition.